# Using secrets with same key stored in either secrets.json or Environment Variable depending on environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I have seen similar questions on SO, but no answers or examples of how to do it.
According to MS DOCS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows it should be possible to store secrets in environment variables when deploying to staging and/or production environments.

When I am working in development mode, then I use the dotnet user-secrets CLI, which generates a secrets.json, and works perfectly fine while in development mode.

The headache is once I leave development mode, and setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Production. I cannot figure out how to use the same key-tag in my code, without creating some custom.

For exaple, in my code I refer to the secret using a key name: "My:Secrets:ClientSecret" (in secrets.json represented as:

```
{
    "My:Secrets:ClientSecret": "SomeSecretValueInHere"
}
```

So when I in my .net 6 code, refer to this key in configuration by the following example:

```
var clientSecret = Configuration["My:Secrets:ClientSecret"];
```

It works while in development as they are stored using secrets.json, but if I build to Production, and having a "My:Secrets:ClientSecret" (also tried to replce the : with double underscore __ without any differences), stored my System variables with the value "SomeSecretValueInHere", then the clientSecret variable in my .net 6 code is left empty.

Could anyone please provide an example of how to do this? I don't have access to using secrets managers like AzureKeyVault or similar, and I would really try to avoid creating custom code saying pseudo

```
if(Environment.IsDevelopment)
    UseUserSecret
else
    LoadEnvironmentVariablesInSomeWay
```

Using the following builder to create the configuration in code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)
    .Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), true);
```

Comment: How are you providing the production values to your application in production mode? What do you mean by using your system variables? You shouldn't have to change how your application reads config from `Configuration` when `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is set to production.

Comment: @DavidSpence The point is I'm not sure how/where I store the values in production mode. When I wrote system variables I refer to system variables on the OS (in my case Windows System Variables), which seems to be the wrong place as they have no effect at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#non-prefixed-environment-variables) if you have environment variables included n configuration sources (for example as done in the default setup) then `Configuration["My:Secrets:ClientSecret"]` will be read from `My__Secrets__ClientSecret` environment variable (unless `My:Secrets:ClientSecret` from earlier config source in the pipeline as for example from CLI args in the default setup) i.e. should be the same as `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("My__Secrets__ClientSecret");`.

Note that based on how and on which OS the environment variable is set up you might need to reboot/log out or start the app from the same terminal where you set the variable.

Comment: I forgot the mention that the application is a web api running on IIS. It sounds easy that the default configuration builder is reading from environment variables, perhaps it is my leaking knowledge of IIS that is playing here, but where are the environment varaibles stored in IIS hosted applications? I used system variables on Windows which seems to have no effect, but that could be because I misunderstood the meaning of environment variables.

Comment: @grmihel it should work AFAIK (have you tried to recycle app pool/reboot the machine?). Also you can add app specific environment settings via [iis config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/environmentvariables/) also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72270899/2501279)

Comment: Works as system environment variable, but after a reboot of the machine after changing the value. I'm not sure if there is better/easier way to make changing values reflecting, but it works at least.